# How to open the python documentation?

Tags: python-3.x, documentation, pydoc

I downloaded and installed python 3 from the official website for Mac Os.
In the setup there was a checkmark for the docs.

> This package installs the python documentation at a location that is
>   useable for pydoc and IDLE.

However I cannot locate it.
**How can I open the docs or where are they located?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac Os they are located at

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/English.lproj/Documentation/index.html